# Itext 7 pdf text extraction page origin

Tags: itext

When using Itext 7 to extract texts from a pdf document, most of my tested documents use the standard coordinate system where the origin is bottom left of the page.
In some cases though, the origin seems to be **top left** and I get the texts in reverse order (bottom line to top line instead of top line to bottom line).
I read in the docs that using transformations the origin can be munipulated so I guess for some of my pdf's that is what happened.

Question is:  how can I know when extracting the texts where the origin is?

I already checked page GetOrientation(), GetMediaBox and GetCropBox but those do not seem to bring an asnwer.

**EDIT**

Find the solution for this problem in this post: [Itext 7 bug with GetCtm() on pages>1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70652453/itext-7-bug-with-getctm-on-pages1/70653842)

Comment: Which text extraction strategy do you use? The simple one extracts the text in the order it is drawn (which often is the desired order but may be pretty arbitrary) while the location one sorts top to bottom, left to right.

Comment: I implemented the IEventListener and when an event occurs, check if the eventdata is TextRenderInfo. If so use the textRenderInfo.GetTextMatrix() elements 6 and 7 for X and Y position.
Furthermore for landscape oriented pages - GetPage(n).GetOrientation() -  I do some math to recalculate the X and Y but this is not relevant here as the orientation with the reverse order is 0.

Comment: Ah, so you use a custom strategy. Ok, the origin can be anywhere, inside the page, on its edges, or outsides, see the crop box. Thus, one should simply not rely on its position but simply compare the coordinates of the textRenderInfo text chunks. On a non-rotated page with upright text you can sort them from high to low y coordinate to get a top-to-bottom order. If that doesn't work with your problem PDFs, please share them for analysis.

Comment: I understand all of this. My question is: how can I know IF i have to revert the lines (or Y positions) or not?

Comment: You don't have to revert if you calculated the coordinates correctly. If you think you have to revert for some specific pdfs, please share them for analysis.

Comment: An example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sheeUCK_pl9KGk8XHVLcAjPx3HYyTAHi

Comment: "You don't have to revert if you calculated the coordinates correctly" : agreed!

Question is: what is the proper calculation method. 

I'm not using the I11, I12, I21 & I22 to calculate X & Y and i definitly should. Can't find how (meanwhile I found out that when lines are reverted, I22 is negative (most often -1)).

I alos found this link that mentions this topic: https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/ebooks/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-for-net/chapter-2-adding-low-level-content-net

Comment: As the solution to your next question also resolved this one, I'll close this as duplicate of the next one even though these questions appear very dissimilar at first glance.