# Itext 7 bug with GetCtm() on pages>1

Tags: itext, itext7

Context:

- extract text from a pdf
- using the IEventListener - TextRenderInfo
- a pdf document with more than one page
- c# .net core program

Issue:
To calculate the exact X,Y position of a text I use this code:

```
var textMatrix =textRenderInfo.GetTextMatrix().Multiply(textRenderInfo.GetGraphicsState().GetCtm());
float X = textMatrix.Get(6);
float Y = textMatrix.Get(7);
```

This works ok for the first page. For subsequent pages the CTM seems to be calculated to:  Power(ctm, pagenumber) and the X,Y result is obviously not correct.

More clarification: I have a document with a date repeated on every page on the exact same location. By consequence, it's text matrix is the same on every page. But the CTM looks like this for page 1:

```
{0,05   0   0
0   0,05    0
0   0   1}
```

For page 2:

```
{0,0025000002   0   0
0   0,0025000002    0
0   0   1}
```

For page 3:

```
{0,000125   0   0
0   0,000125    0
0   0   1}
```

Etc ...
So it looks that each value is powered by the pagenumber. Could this be a bug?

Answer (score 0):

> Could this be a bug?

More likely a case of incorrect API usage...

Unfortunately you don't show your pivotal code. I assume, though, that you re-use the same `PdfCanvasProcessor` for all pages. Have you considered the note in the `ProcessPageContent` documentation?

```c#
/// <summary>Processes PDF syntax.</summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Processes PDF syntax.
/// <strong>Note:</strong> If you re-use a given
/// <see cref="PdfCanvasProcessor"/>
/// , you must call
/// <see cref="Reset()"/>
/// </remarks>
/// <param name="page">the page to process</param>
public virtual void ProcessPageContent(PdfPage page)
```

*([PdfCanvasProcessor.cs](https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet/blob/develop/itext/itext.kernel/itext/kernel/pdf/canvas/parser/PdfCanvasProcessor.cs#L268))*

I.e.

> **Note:** If you re-use a given `PdfCanvasProcessor`, you must call `Reset()` [between `ProcessPageContent` calls]

Comment: Mkl, thanks for the help. I got where I wanted to get with your help. I would like to mark this post as solution, but I think my 'reputation' doesn't allow to do so.

Comment: To *mark this post as solution* simply click the check mark at the upper left of the answer (not the voting arrows, the check mark thereunder).