# Why X,Y-coordinates (returned by iText) differ for the same text sitting in the same spot on different pdf pages?

Tags: itext, itext7, text-extraction

Good morning, everyone! I've encountered an issue with iText that might be a bug and am posting it here as suggested by the iText guidelines.

If we look at this file - [South Africa Tariff](https://www.sars.gov.za/wp-content/uploads/Legal/SCEA1964/LAPD-LPrim-Tariff-2012-04-Schedule-No-1-Part-1-Chapters-1-to-99.pdf) - we'll see its pages have the landscape orientation (Rotation=90) and show the same text (**Date: 2022-04-29**) in the same spot (top-left corner of the page). For our test, p.1,2,3 would suffice.

Now, if we implement our own `TextExtractionStrategy` and inspect X,Y-coordinates of the character "D" (from the above-mentioned text), we'll see they differ from page to page:

- p.1 **(X=32.07, Y=36.0)**,
- p.2 **(X=559.0, Y=32.07)**,
- p.3 **(X=562.93,Y=559.0)**, where:

X is retrieved from `getDescentLine().getStartPoint().get(0)`,
Y is retrieved from `getDescentLine().getStartPoint().get(1)`.

All 3 pages have the same **CropBox [0,0,595,842]**.

I would expect to see the same X,Y across all pages. Other products - xpdf, PdfBox and iTextSharp - do show consistent coordinates for "D" on all pages.

Does this look like a **bug** in iText to your eyes? If anyone from the iText Team picks it up & needs more info, I'd be happy to help.

Kind regards, Sit Anko.

P.S. Thanks to mkl, here is an idea of how to deal with this: PdfCanvasProcessor needs to be reset or recreated before processing a new page, e.g.

```
PdfDocument reader = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(filepath));
FilteredEventListener listener = new FilteredEventListener();
var strategy = listener.AttachEventListener(new myTextLocationStrategy());
PdfCanvasProcessor processor = new PdfCanvasProcessor(listener);
for (int page = 1; page <= reader.GetNumberOfPages(); page++)
{
    processor.Reset(); // <--!!! reset the processor 
    //processor = new PdfCanvasProcessor(listener); //alternatively, recreate it
    processor.ProcessPageContent(reader.GetPage(page));
}
```

There's a similar question: [Itext 7 bug with GetCtm() on pages>1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70652453/itext-7-bug-with-getctm-on-pages1/70653842#70653842)

Comment: I'm not at my PC currently, so i can only guess. One possible cause, though: the different pages simply may have different coordinate systems! Have you checked the respective crop boxes? They tell you the coordinates of corners of the respective visible page area. While often 0, 0 is in the lower left corner, it does not need to be so. And another possible reason would be the re-use of objects carrying the graphics state - that might make parsing on the next page start with a dirty state, e.g. the wrong starting transformation matrix.

Comment: Thank you, KJ & mkl - I've checked CropBox and it's the same on p.1,2,3 (edited my question to reflect this).

Comment: Have you checked my other guess? Do you probably re-use parsing objects from page to page? (As you don't show any code, all we can do is guess...) You asked in your question *'Does this look like a bug in iText to your eyes?'* - no, it's unlikely that it's an iText bug, more likely a bug in your own text extraction strategy or your use thereof.

Comment: Thanks, mkl - you're absolutely right. PdfCanvasProcessor's ProcessPageContent(), when called for p.2,3,etc. doesn't do a "full reset" and continues with the Graphical State pulled from the stack. Before processing a new page, one either needs to create a new PdfCanvasProcessor or call its Reset() method.

Comment: @mkl - I feel daft, but I can't find how to mark your comment as the answer, so I just added a P.S. to the question block.

Comment: *"I can't find how to mark your comment as the answer"* - no wonder because you cannot. ;) Only actual answers can be marked as accepted answer. As your problem essentially has turned out to be the same as in that other info, though, we can simply close your question as duplicate thereof.